# Leaflet.js path stroke offset

Tags: leaflet

I've got a situation where I'm loading geoJson and the polygons have complete coverage over a map area. The stroke by default goes to the outside of the polygon. As all my polygons are close to touching I'm getting the stoke overlapping with other polygons stoke!

Mapbox GL seems to do it with [line-offset](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#paint-line-line-offset)

I've tried looking in map places, found a [github issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3665) asking for the same thing, but it's stale. It looks to be a limitation on SVG's, so I'm wondering if there's a workaround, or I can manipulate my geoJSON to make gaps between the polygons?

Comment: https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineOffset

Comment: Thanks @IvanSanchez I've looked and I'm not sure this does quite what I need, seems to add another polygon with an offset, rather than just he stroke.

Comment: If that's a problem, use different Leaflet layers to draw the polygon's stroke and the polygon's fill.